# SSHD + full encryption: performance boost?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, encryption

SSHD on itself as I heard is pretty nice.
But what if I would full encrypt the SSHD with Truecrypt or whatever? Do I get still some performance boost?

I'm just asking because as I understood SSHD is trying to use important tasks/programs on the SSD part BUT because everything is encrypted -> every part is randomly distributed right? So the parts of import stuff are after an encryption maybe not on the SSD part.

Answer (score 4):

SSHD optimize on block-level which **blocks** to store on the SSD part. Blocks that are accessed often are stored there.

Full disk encryption like TrueCrypt or dm-crypt use block-based encryption. Therefore there is a direct mapping between physical blocks and logical blocks (although they do not need to be the same size. So the mapping could be x physical blocks to y logical blocks). So if you access a certain file often, you also access the same physical block often and the SSHD can optimize.

So using an SSHD together with encryption should not change anything.

(If there are SSHD that require a driver to interact with the OS, things could change. The WD-Black² is such a drive, but the WD Black² does not transparently make use of the SSD part.)